# Find pattern in doc & print proceeding 3 line whenever pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I have the requirement to find out a date pattern from a `.doc` file and whenever the pattern matches then it will print the preceding 3 lines of that match.

But as output I am getting only the 1st match and for another match I am not getting any result.

Below is the code :

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{2,4}') ##specify pattern which needs to identify

mo = phoneNumRegex.search(string)      ##finding pattern on varible 'string' which holds file value

for index, line in enumerate(lines):  # enumerate the list and loop through it
       
   if mo.group() in line:  # check if the current line has your substring

        print("".join(lines[max(0,index-3):min(index+3, len(lines)-0)])) ## Defining index value from 0 and priniting previous 3 line & after 3 line if any match find
```

Comment: Could you share the value of `string` which is the file to be searched and the expected output? The problem to solve would be clearer that way.

Comment: You are not running the regex against the lines, you run it at the beginning, before the loop, against some "string". Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

`re.search()` stops after the first match, so this is why you only find one. You can either use `re.findall()` or move the regex matching into your loop. Then there is no need to compare the file against the matches.

Side note: Double check your edge cases to see if you need to modify your regex:

- Your regex will also match if there are more than 4 digits in the number. I assume you want exactly 2-4? If so, you could e.g. add a word boundary (`\b`) at the end of your expression.
- Your regex will also match on any line that has a word followed by a number of at least two digits. If you don't want this, you can e.g. modify your regex by adding line start (`^`) and ending ( `$`) delimiters at the start/end of your expression.

See https://regex101.com/r/nPjpX2/2.

Example:

```
import re

phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{2,4}')

string = '''This is a multiline string that contains
some text and also addresses and numbers that match your regex

Guy Incognito
742 Evergreen Terrace
Springfield
Whatever 1234

some more text and another address, but a longer number

Another One 
12 Two St
Washington
PREFIX 654321

and a third one

Ms Final
555 Wall Street
NY
Something 99

Beware of some number, like 33, appearing somewhere in between'''


lines = string.splitlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if phoneNumRegex.search(line):
         print('\n'.join(lines[max(0,idx-3):idx]))
         print('---')
```

Output for regex `[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{2,4}`:

```
Guy Incognito
742 Evergreen Terrace
Springfield
---
Another One 
12 Two St
Washington
---
Ms Final
555 Wall Street
NY
---
NY
Something 99

---
```

Output for regex `^[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{2,4}$`:

```
Guy Incognito
742 Evergreen Terrace
Springfield
---
Ms Final
555 Wall Street
NY
---
```

Comment: Note: Since your regex was named `phoneNumRegex` I used addresses in my example. I now see that you are looking for some kind of date string. My code will work all the same.